# How can I make Perl recognize paths with '~'?

Tags: perl, home-directory, tilde-expansion

> **Possible Duplicate:** 
>   [How do I find a user's home directory in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475357/how-do-i-find-a-users-home-directory-in-perl)

I'm running Ubuntu.

Whenever I pass a Perl script a path that starts with `~` (e.g. `~/Documents/file.txt`) it fails finding it. I must pass the canonical path (e.g. `/home/dave/Documents/file.txt`).

Why is that?

Can I make Perl recognize `~` paths?

**UPDATE**

All the suggested solutions include changing the code in the scripts. I would like for a solution that would not involve any changes to the scripts themselves (since not all of them are mine). Perhaps something in the way Bash works?

The updated version of the question [was posted at Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/205638/).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I find a user's home directory in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475357/how-do-i-find-a-users-home-directory-in-perl)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For a reliable (and easy) cross-platform method, try [File::HomeDir](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::HomeDir):

```
use File::HomeDir;
print File::HomeDir->my_home;
```

Comment: I except this as my original phrasing of the question was not that bright. For my 'true' question - see update 2 at the OP.

Answer (score 9):

You can pass the path to `glob` to get it expanded.

Comment: Breaks on `~/a filename with spaces.txt`.

Comment: @Ven'Tatsu: So it does!  But weirdly, create 2 files, `abcd.txt` and `e gh.txt`.  `glob "\Qabc?.txt"` returns just `abc?.txt` (i.e. unexpanded, `?` doesn't match `d`) while `glob "\Qe g?.txt"` returns `e gh.txt` (i.e. the `?` matches `h` now for some reason).  My brain hurts.

Comment: @j_random_hacker, strange, `bash` and `csh` shell expansion treats the `\?` that results from `quotemeta` in both cases as a literal `?`, not match any one character. I don't know why `perl` is giving differing results.

Comment: j_random_hacker, the [`glob` documentation](http://p3rl.org/glob) clearly says that the function splits on whitespace. Therefore you must quote it. `glob '~/a\ filename\ with\ spaces.txt'` works as intended.

Answer (score 6):

The [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) function understands standard Unix file globbing.

```
my $file = glob('~/Documents/file.txt');
```

Comment: Breaks on `~/a filename with spaces.txt`.

Answer (score 4):

Try to replace `~` with `$ENV{HOME}`

Comment: @Wooble, indeed, you could also use `((getpwnam('someuser'))[7])`

Answer (score 3):

Use angle-quotes, not double-quotes:

```
open(my $fh, "< :crlf :encoding(cp1252)",
              <~/Documents/file.txt>)
    || die "couldn't open Winblose text file ~/Documents/file.txt: $!";
```

The `<xxx>` iteration operator, which people usually think of as syntactic sugar for the `readline` function, instead calls the `glob` function if there are shell metachars in *xxx*, and tilde count as one of those.

You might prefer an open mode of `<:encoding(Latin1)`. It just depends on the file.

Answer (score 3):

From Bruno's comment, you could do it this way:

```
$path =~ s/^~(\w*)/ ( getpwnam( $1 || $ENV{USER} ))[7] /e;
```

The `e` flag replaces the expression with the *result* of *executing* or *evaluating* the replace expression.

Answer (score 0):

Kind of late to this one, but an easy solution is to double escape the spaces in a filename/path so that glob doesn't break.  Not so sure it's portable, but it's easy enough to do on platforms that support this (maybe even windows?) and then the resultant value stored in a var allows for easy usage.  A regex could whipped up to replace spaces in filenames with a double backslash escape.  Example, sans regex:

```
my $dir_name  = "~/Shared\\ Items/a\\ filename\\ with\\ spaces.txt";
my $glob_name = glob($dir_name);

print "exists!\n" if -e $glob_name;
```