# Perl use module, keep getting Undefined subroutine &main error

Tags: mysql, perl

I have a perl module DB.pm, inside is somthing like:

```
package GUI::DB;
use strict;
use DBI;
use vars qw(@ISA @EXPORT);
use Exporter;
@ISA = qw(Exporter);
@EXPORT = qw(fun);
sub fun {
    my $dsn = "DBI:mysql:database=test";
    return $dsn;
}
```

---

Then I wrote test.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use lib '~/Downloads/GUI'; #Here is the path of the DB.pm module.
use DB;
my $aa = fun();
```

I have been trying to fix it for hours, I tried to use comment `perl -l /path/to/file aa.pl` and it gave me no error but the script didn't run at all, I am purely new to Perl, really stuck.
Please help me.

EDIT: So the module's name is DB.pm and folder's name is GUI now, and I an using `use DB` in my script, still doesn't work, where should I save the DB.pm file?

Comment: Did you forget to say `use HA;` ?

Comment: The convention is to define a package called `GUI::DB` in a file called `GUI/DB.pm`, and to import it with `use GUI::DB` to avoid the very problems you are having.

Comment: Yep ,it should be use HA; but it doesn't work still.

Comment: I changed the folder name to GUI, counld not name a file with '/', and now it give me `Can't locate GUI/DB.pm in @INC (@INC contains: ~/Downloads/GUI /etc/perl ...the lib paths..`

Comment: what does "counld not name a file with '/'" mean?

Comment: Can't name a file with name like 'aaa/bbb' in linux

Comment: you need to `mkdir aaa ` to make the directory before renaming it

Comment: `~` is not expanded by perl. Use $ENV{HOME} instead if you're on a Unix system.

Answer (score 4):

`use HA;` does a couple of things.  First, it finds a file HA.pm in the perl library paths (`@INC`).  Second, it calls `HA::->import()` to allow the HA module to do whatever initialization/exporting it wants; this relies on the module's package matching its filename.  If it doesn't, this initialization is quietly skipped (method calls to an `import` method don't generate an error even if the method does not exist).

So explicitly call import on the package you want, or make the package name match the filename.

Comment: I changed the module's name to DB.pm, and I an using use DB(also GUI::DB) in my script, i also tried my $aa= DB->fun();still doesn't work, where should I save the DB.pm file?

Comment: normally perl will look for modules in the current directory, in addition to other places.  does `perl -wle'print for @INC'` show `.` as one of rows?  if so, put DB.pm under ./GUI/

Answer (score 3):

Perl doesn't understand `~`, see [How do I find a user's home directory in Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475357/how-do-i-find-a-users-home-directory-in-perl/1475363)

You also need to give `use lib` the directory which `GUI/DB.pm` is in and use `GUI::DB`:

```
use lib $ENV{HOME}."/Downloads";
use GUI::DB;
```