Why is glob failing after the first iteration of foreach
I'm new to Perl and seem to have come across some behavior that I don't understand and was unexpected.
I'm trying to write a function that attempts to load a config file from a list of possible locations stored in an array. I'm using a foreach loop to iterate over the array and check for the existence of the file, but after the first iteration, glob is returning undef, even when the value passed to it is a static, single-quoted string. Why?
Here is the code:
package MyPackage;
use warnings; use strict;

our @ConfigSearchPaths = (".", "~");
our $DefaultConfigName = ".my_config_file";

sub load_user_config
{
    my ( $obj, $filename ) = @_;

    $filename ||= $DefaultConfigName;

    CONFIG_SEARCH: foreach my $search_path (@ConfigSearchPaths)
    {
        my $file_path = glob( "$search_path/$filename" );

        # I added this line to test if the issue was related to interpolation
        # but to my surprise, this also returns 'undef' after the first iteration.
        my $file_path_2 = glob( '~/.my_config_file' );

        if( -r $file_path )
        {
            # Parse the file...
        }
    }
}


See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/1475357/725418, and the recommended module File::HomeDir.

The answer is in the documentation: see glob.

In scalar context, glob iterates through such filename expansions, returning undef when the list is exhausted.

In other words: in the first iteration, glob returns the file itself; on the second iteration, it returns undef, as there aren't any more matches.
By assigning to something that isn't an aggregate, you are using scalar context. ( See also: Scalar vs List Assignment Operator. )
Keep in mind that in scalar context, glob does not observe the changes to $search_path and instead iterates over the list results of the first call, using the non-interpolated string to "remember" the list being iterated.
If you don't want to iterate, use list context:
    my @file_paths  = glob "$search_path/$filename";  # Captures the whole array
    # or
    my ($file_path) = glob "$search_path/$filename";  # Discards all but the first item

I'd recommend reaching for Path::Tiny or a similar module to handle paths for you.

Or my ( $file_path ) = glob ...; to get one of the matching paths (or undef if there's no match).

Is there any point in using glob for a single, literal path? glob ./.my_config won't even check the file system, it will just return the string.

@TLP: glob expands '~'.

@TLP Why is it relevant if my scripts and modules are internal or not? I'm not going to hard code a bunch of user home directories into my module even if it does stay internal, that's just silly and defaulting to such an approach is bad form that amounts to immediate technical debt. I want consumers of this module to be able to add their own search paths to the array and take advantage of glob's capabilities, and I don't want every caller to have to manually provide their own home directory.

@choroba Thanks for the clarification, I guess I misunderstood what it was trying to convey to me regarding the scalar context. Can you clarify why my $file_path = glob( "$search_path/$filename" ); still returns undef on the second iteration even though $search_path changes? I understand now why the static string starts returning undef, but I would expect the changing $search_path to cause glob to start over every loop?

@ikegami Can you clarify how my ( $file_path ) = glob("$search_path/$filename"); is different from my $file_path = glob( "$search_path/$filename" );?

@LostSnail The scalar context glob will remember the last usage of the glob string, and on the next FOR iteration use the same string again, regardless of the changes to $search. The list context glob will return all values at once, and then forget the string.

I think I understand now. It seems there were a couple things causing confusion, one of which was the scalar vs list context, and the representations for achieving them. I think some of that confusion comes from the inconsistencies with referring to some of these types (e.g. brackets vs parenthesis for arrays). It does still seem a bit odd that in scalar context, the changes to $search_path don't cause glob to start over, but I suppose I'll just have to keep that gotcha in mind as part of my understanding of how Perl works.

@LostSnail See Scalar vs List Assignment Operator
